# How to run two service with different node with voltdb

Tags: voltdb

I have a three node cluster configured for voltdb. Currently 2 applications are running and all the traffic is going to only single node. ( Only one server)

As we have 3 cluster ( 3 nodes) and data is replicated around all the nodes. Can i run one service on one Node and other service on another node? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as both these services use the same database, they can both point to different nodes in the cluster, and VoltDB will reroute the data to the proper partition accordingly.

However, it is recommended to connect applications to all of the nodes in a cluster, so they can send requests to the cluster more evenly. Depending on which client is being used, there are optimizations that send each request to the optimal server based on which partition is involved. This is often called "client affinity". Clients can also simply send to each node in a round-robin style. Both client affinity and round-robin are much more efficient than simply sending all traffic to 1 node.

Also, be cautious of running applications on the same hosts as VoltDB nodes, because they could unpredictably starve the VoltDB process of resources that it needs. However, for applications that behave well and on servers where there are adequate resources, they can be co-located and many VoltDB customers do this.

Full Disclosure: I work at VoltDB.